# second attribute in options_from_collection_for_select

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a options_from_collection_for_select like this :

```
= form_tag url_for(action: :index), method: 'get' do
= select_tag :group_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@groups, :id, :title, ), prompt: "Tickets des groupes", data: {submit_on_change: true}
```

and I would like to add a second attribute in parentheses: the number of tickets of each group so that when I click in my select_tag it would look like :

group #1 (2 tickets)
group #2 (4 tickets)
group #3 (1 ticket)

How do I do add a second attribute ?

Cheers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the :title to a different name, which can be a method on your model

```
= select_tag :group_id, options_from_collection_for_select(@groups, :id, :title_with_tickets), prompt: "Tickets des groupes", data: {submit_on_change: true}
```

Then your model something like:

```
class Group
  def title_with_tickets
    "group #{id} (#{tickets.count} tickets)"
  end
```

Note, the above code assumes you have a relationship tickets on group, so you can call tickets.count and get the count. The code may differ according to your relationship name/type.

Comment: No worries. Counting the records each time you call the method is a slow way to do this though, I'd consider adding a 'counter cache' for storing how many tickets belong to a group, then you can just do tickets_count instead of tickets.count- http://railscasts.com/episodes/23-counter-cache-column